# On SharedPreferences, change variable type from Boolean to Integer

Tags: java, android, android-sharedpreferences

I have a `SharedPreferences`variable that I created before as a `Boolean`type, with all the logic associated with that, as shown on the code bellow:

```
    public Boolean getElementsShow() {
    return elementsShow;
}

public void setElementsShow(Boolean elementsShow) {
    this.elementsShow = elementsShow;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
    editor.putBoolean(ELEMENTSSHOW, elementsShow);
    editor.commit();
}
```

and

```
elementsShow = settings.getBoolean(ELEMENTSSHOW, 0);
```

But, as necessities change, now I need to change this variable and retrive it as an `Integer`:

```
elementsShow = settings.getInt(ELEMENTSSHOW, 0);
```

but as expected, when I change everything to be retrieving as Integer, it gives error 
`java.lang.Boolean cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer` because variables was saved as `Boolean` and now is being accessed as an `Integer`...

I know that I can create a new variable and ignore the previous one created, but is there a way to change the reference to start storing as a `Integer`?

Comment: Short answer: no. A boolean is a booolean, and an integer is an integer. You can always get the boolean value, ask for the value, and return accordingly (if yourValue){return 1}else{return 0}

Or something similar.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html   read this u will get idea about types and understand why its impossible

Comment: Yeah, I figured, I was asking more to clarify myself... I guess, that in the future I'm gonna start to initiate all as `Integer`, since very few things can only be `true` or `false`... your suggestion, unfortunately doesn't help, because I need to save more than 2 values, and it only converts from `false` to 0 and `true` to 1... but thanks wanyway

Comment: the thing is that I don't want to change the variable type, just the reference type to the `SharedPreferences`... like reset, and then start to store as a different type

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store more than 2 values you cant use a boolean, cause boolean just work with 2 values.

Last edit:

```
    elementsShow = settings.getBoolean(ELEMENTSSHOW, false); 
    if(elementsShow == false){
 editor.putInt(ELEMENTSSHOW, elementsShow);
    }
}
```

Is this what you want?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, but that doesn't help me because, I still can only store 2 values, and the purpose of changing to `Integer` is to store more than two ...

Comment: If you want to store more than 2 values you cant use a boolean to integer, cause boolean just work with 2 values.

Comment: I haven't tried, but I bet it will not work...If I have the variable as `Integer`, the `getBoolean` will give me an error, and if I have the variable as `Boolean` the `putInt` will also give me an error... the solution to your proposal will be surrounding with try and catch, to get whatever type is saved... but I believe that is not a good solution... got any other ideas?

Comment: Your problem has an easy solution...just don't store a boolean and store and int instead...